# Check if textbox contains a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently working on a digital assistant website which is based around JavaScript and jQuery. The user can type in questions or tell the assistant things into the textbox and the assistant will respond with something relevant to the input. What I am planning to implement is to check if the textbox contains a number (intager) and if it does some sort of function will run. The concept sounds fairly simple and but I am having trouble. I have been searching around for a bit but I can't seem to find anything which will work with my code.

I will add my JavaScript and the nessacary parts of the HTML. But I am warning you, the code is messy.

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document
function submitted() {
    var srch = document.getElementById("srch");
    command();
    getPlaceHolder();
    srch.value = "";
}

function searchKeyPress(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        //document.getElementById('btn').click();
        submitted();
    }
}

function goBtn() {
    submitted();
}

function refreshBtn() {
    getWelcome();
}

function stClock() {
    window.setTimeout("stClock()", 1000);
    today = new Date();
    self.status = today.toString();
}

function getWelcome() {
    var ar = new Array(20)
    ar[0] = "What's on your mind?";
    ar[1] = "How can I help?";
    ar[2] = "Anything you need help with?";
    ar[3] = "Ask me anything";
    ar[4] = "What can I help you with?";
    ar[5] = "What would you like me to do?";
    ar[6] = "What can I do for you?";
    ar[7] = "Need help with anything?";
    ar[8] = "Need someone to talk to?";
    ar[9] = "I'm here to help";
    ar[10] = "Anything you need to know?";
    ar[11] = "How else can I help?";
    ar[12] = "What can I do now?";
    ar[13] = "Need anything?";
    ar[14] = "Any problems you need solving?";
    ar[15] = "Hello, how do you do?";
    ar[16] = "Hi there";
    ar[17] = "Hi, I'm aurum";
    ar[18] = "Hello there";
    ar[19] = "How do you do?";
    var now = new Date();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ar[sec % 20];
}

function getPlaceHolder() {
    var ar = new Array(20)
    ar[0] = "What's on your mind?";
    ar[1] = "How can I help?";
    ar[2] = "Anything you need help with?";
    ar[3] = "Ask me anything";
    ar[4] = "What can I help you with?";
    ar[5] = "What would you like me to do?";
    ar[6] = "What can I do for you?";
    ar[7] = "Need help with anything?";
    ar[8] = "Need someone to talk to?";
    ar[9] = "I'm here to help";
    ar[10] = "Anything you need to know?";
    ar[11] = "How else can I help?";
    ar[12] = "What can I do now?";
    ar[13] = "Need anything?";
    ar[14] = "Any problems you need solving?";
    ar[15] = "Hello, how do you do?";
    ar[16] = "Hi there";
    ar[17] = "Hi, I'm aurum";
    ar[18] = "Hello there";
    ar[19] = "How do you do?";
    var now = new Date();
    var sec = now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementsByName('srch')[0].placeholder=ar[sec % 20];
}

function command() {
        var srchVar = document.getElementById("srch");
        var srch = srchVar.value;
        var t = srch;
        var outputElement = document.getElementById('output');
        if (srch == '') {
            outputElement.innerHTML = "How can I help you, if you don't say anything?";
        }
        else if (srch.indexOf('about') != -1) {
            outputElement.innerHTML = "Hello, I'm Aurum. I was designed by Omar Latreche to help people answer their questions. However, I also like to talk to people aswell as answer their questions.";
        }
        else if (srch.indexOf('time') != -1) {
            outputElement.innerHTML = 'The current time according to your computer is' + ShowTime(new Date());
        }
        else {
            if (confirm("I am sorry but for some reason I don't understand. You could either repeat that or would you like to search Google for that instead?") == true) {
                window.open('https://www.google.co.uk/#q=' + srch, '_blank');
            }
            else { /* Nothing */ }
        }
    }
    //Show time in 12hour format
var ShowTime = (function() {
    function addZero(num) {
        return (num >= 0 && num < 10) ? "0" + num : num + "";
    }
    return function(dt) {
        var formatted = '';
        if (dt) {
            var hours24 = dt.getHours();
            var hours = ((hours24 + 11) % 12) + 1;
            formatted = [formatted, [addZero(hours), addZero(dt.getMinutes())].join(":"), hours24 > 11 ? "PM" : "AM"].join(" ");
        }
        return formatted;
    };
})();
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="getWelcome(); getPlaceHolder();">
    <div class="output" id="output">
        An error has occoured. Please make sure you have JavaScript enabled in your browser.
    </div>
    <div class="cont">
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <div class="search-cont">
                <input class="search-field" id="srch" name="srch" onkeypress="searchKeyPress(event);" placeholder="ask me anything" spellcheck="false"> <input class="refresh" onclick="refreshBtn()" title="Refresh the conversation" type="button"> <input class="go" onclick="goBtn()" type="button">
            </div>
        </div><br>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I really appreciate any help provided. Thanks, Omar.

PS. I apologies for the long paragraph but that is the only way I could think to explain what I need.

PPS. If you need any more information on my project just incase, the URL is http://omarlatreche.tk/aurum/

Comment: "if text contains a number". That can be done with regex, depending what you want. Is asd3ef valid? or it has to be in the format of asd 3 ef?

Comment: I've tried multiple regex's, but none seem to be doing the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function I came up with to check for number:

```
function checkNum() {
    text = document.getElementById('srch').value;
    valArr = document.getElementById('srch').value.split(' ');

    for (i = 0; i < valArr.length; i++) {
        if (isNaN(valArr[i])==false) {
            alert("Number found");
        }
    }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nnoosjch/)

I called the function in the *goBtn()* function.

Comment: @omar_latreche Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

can you explain this line?

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = [0].innerHTML=ar[sec % 20];
```

shouldn't it be

```
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ar[sec % 20];
```

Comment: Oh, yeah. Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @omar_latreche ok, well since this is stackoverflow, now you need to find a small part of your code that is not working (eg, at a minimum, delete all but 2 of each of your arrays), and ask a specific question explaining what you thought a certain line of code would do and what it does.

Comment: What do you mean "delete all but 2 of each of your arrays"?

Comment: @omar_latreche  I mean you post hundreds of lines of code and most of it is your different array options.  You need, for the sake of the question, to delete almost everything and just post the very essence of your code, with only 2 or 3 items instead of 20.